# Chrome's address bar "lock" timeout?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm experiencing interesting issue that only occurs when I'm logged in chrome browser using our company account ("Managed by your organization").

I often refresh page by clicking into address bar and pressing enter (sometimes it's better then F5 key because of forms), but I have to wait about 2 seconds before the chrome allows me to send the new request. The address bar seems like it's locked somehow for a short period of time.

It doesn't happen with my personal chrome account or in incognito mode.
Also tested with no extensions.

Does anyone have a similar issue? Or how to disable it?

Thank you for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's caused by "Autocomplete searches and URLs". You can turn it off in "Settings > Sync and Google services > Autocomplete searches and URLs".

I believe it's probably a bug.